# Finding the Maclaurin Series for $\sqrt{1+x^2}$

Tags: taylor-expansion

I can't find the Maclaurin series for $\sqrt{1+x^2}$.  Every time it try to find it I get the Maclaurin series for $\sqrt {1+x}$.  Can someone explain it to me?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you try finding the Maclaurin series for $\sqrt{1+y}$ first, then make the substitution $y = x^2$?

Comment: So then you can find the series for $\sqrt{1+x}$ an then replace $x$ with $x^2$ to get the desired series.

Comment: What do you mean "every time it try to find it"...? Can you use the definition?

Comment: If you replace $ y $ or $ x $ with $ x^2$ you still get 0.

Comment: @MPW:  If I replace $x$ with $x^2$, it will still equal $0$ when you find the derivatives of the $\sqrt {1+x^2} $.

Comment: Best if you show your work. You're doing something wrong, and there's no way to tell what it is without seeing what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{d\sqrt{1+x^2}}{dx}=x(1+x^2)^{-1/2}$$
$$\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}=\frac{d^2\sqrt{1+x^2}}{dx^2}=-x^2(1+x^2)^{-3/2}+(1+x^2)^{-1/2}=(1+x^2)^{-3/2}$$
Thus, the first derivative at zero is indeed zero, but the second is non zero, and is equal to one when $x=0$.

Of course, you could have just used the series for $\sqrt{1+x}$, and substituted $x\rightarrow x^2$. In that case the first derivative would be non-zero, but it would now be the coefficient of $x^2$. In both methods the coefficient of $x$ is zero, as it should be since the function is clearly even.

Comment: Where did your $ x $ in front of $ (1+x^2)^{-1/2} $ come from? Shouldn't the derivative just be $(1/2)(1+x^2)^{-1/2} $?

Comment: @Ethan - it's the internal derivative that you have to multiply by $d(x^2)=2x$

Comment: Haha, oh wow.  I entirely forgot about that.  There would be my problem!

Comment: this is probably a stupid question, but how did you simplify that addition problem at the end?

Comment: @Ethan - multiply and divide the second term by $(1+x^2)^-1$, then you'll get $(-x^2+1+x^2)(1+x^2)^{-3/2}$

Comment: Ah, okay.  Thank you!  A final question; what made you think to multiply by $\frac {(1+x^2)^{-1}}{ (1+x^2)^{-1}}$?

Comment: @Ethan - just looking for a way to simplify. You don't really need to simplify to get the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use the binomial theorem. For $n \ge 1$ you have that:
\begin{align}
\binom{1/2}{n}
  &= \frac{(1/2)^{\underline{n}}}{n!} \\
  &= \frac{\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{2} - 1\right)
             \ldots \left(\frac{1}{2} - n + 1\right)}{n!} \\
  &= \frac{1 \cdot (-3) \cdot (-5) \cdot \ldots \cdot (- 2 n - 3)}{2^n n!} \\
  &= \frac{(-1)^{n - 1} (2 n - 2)!}{n! (n - 1)!} \\
  &= (-1)^{n - 1} \frac{1}{2^{2 n - 1} n}\binom{2 n - 2}{n - 1}
\end{align}
Thus:
$$
\sqrt{1 + x^2}
  = 1 + \sum_{n \ge 1}  
          (-1)^{n - 1} \frac{1}{2^{2 n - 1} n}\binom{2 n - 2}{n - 1} x^{2 n}
$$
To prove the (generalized) binomial theorem in turn is rather easy:
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d} u^n} (1 + u)^a
  = a^{\underline{n}} (1 + u)^{a - n} \\ 
$$
Evaluate at $u = 0$, all that is left is $a^{\underline{n}} = a (a - 1) \ldots (a -n + 1)$